# Java Diameter message not routable

Tags: java, diameter-protocol

I am using java diameter library to implement Charging client. Capabilities Exchange Answer from server is OK but when I send charging request. Client returns `SimpleSyncClient.sendRequest(): not routable`. I am using [this library](http://i1.dk/JavaDiameter/). Anybody have any idea why this is happening? If CEA is OK then why are messages are not routable?

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind the "not routable" is the Capability Exchange Answer should be having originator host as some domain. Update the same in the host file in driver it should solve the issue.